# Как дождаться конца воспроизведения звука в Naudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

В моей программе необходимо воспроизводить несколько раз один звук.
Как это сделать один раз разобрался, а вот когда воспроизвожу два раза бипер начинает пищать прямо сразу после начала воспроизведения музыки, перебиваяя её.
Подскажите что не так?

```
    public void playmusic(int ce)
    {
        int i=0;            
        if (ce > 1)
        {
            while (i < 3 && i<ce)
            {
                if (i == 0 && ce==1)
                {
                    Console.Beep(500, 1000);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    PlayMp3();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else{
                Console.Beep(500, 500);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                PlayMp3();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);}           
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void PlayMp3()
    {
        this.waveOut = new WaveOut(); 
        this.mp3FileReader = new Mp3FileReader("peep.mp3");
        this.waveOut.Init(mp3FileReader);
        this.waveOut.Play();
        this.waveOut.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
    }

    private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseWaveOut();
    }

    void CloseWaveOut()
    {
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
        }
        if (mp3FileReader != null)
        {
            mp3FileReader.Dispose();
            mp3FileReader = null;
        }
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Play выполняется в отдельном потоке. Чтобы в текущем потоке дождаться завершения проигрывания mp3, можно использовать ManualResetEvent:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Threading;

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var w = new WaveOut();
    var r = new Mp3FileReader(@"c:\temp\test.mp3");
    w.Init(r);
    w.Play();
    var re = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    w.PlaybackStopped += (s, e) => re.Set();  
    mre.WaitOne(); // ждем вызов re.Set()
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

Comment: наконецто добрался до компа! спасибо!