# Регулирование звука приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно отключить/включить звук в приложении? И какой класс лучше всего использовать для проигрывания mp3?

Comment: _"для работы с mp3"_ -- для редактирования / записи / проигрывания? 
посмотрите [naudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/)

Comment: Для обычного проигрывания

Comment: пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477364/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-naudio/477423#477423)

Comment: NAudio это сторонняя библиотека?

Comment: да. а приложение под WinForms или WPF? в .net есть SoundPlayer и MediaPlayer.

Comment: Приложение WinForms

Comment: в SoundPlayer нет регулировки звука. надо делать через DllImport.  пример [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42b46e40-4d4a-48f8-8681-9b0167cfe781/attenuating-soundplayer-volume?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: SoundPlayer работает только с wav. Буду использовать  WindowsMediaPlayer тогда.

Comment: @Stack, я просмотрел Ваш пример, он для работы только с wav