# Возможно ли снять блокировку из другого потока?

Tags: .net, многопоточность

При попытке снять блокировку монитора из другого потока выбрасывается исключение

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' occurred in Test - Smth.exe
>
> Additional information: Для не синхронизированного блока кода вызван метод синхронизации объектов.

Пример кода:

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Module All
  Sub Main()
    Dim Obj As New Object

    Monitor.Enter(Obj)
    Call (New Thread(Sub() Monitor.Exit(Obj))).Start()

    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Возможно ли как-то снять блокировку из того потока, который её НЕ устанавливал?

Comment: в такой ситуации можно использовать ManualResetEvent пример -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477423/196972)

Comment: @Stack: Лучше по идее использовать более новый `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Comment: @Stack, по поводу того, зачем, пошли в [соседний вопрос](/q/484669/178988) :)

Comment: @VladD, тоже. Может даже вспомнишь - мы когда-то в чате обсуждали.

Comment: @VladD _"Лучше по идее использовать более новый ManualResetEventSlim"_ -- в общем да, но если есть как минимум два потока, то думаю можно просто ManualResetEvent. хотя точно не знаю, не проверял.

Comment: @Stack: Microsoft рекомендует Slim- версию во всех случаях (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbefs30%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Хотя в принципе, это, конечно, микрооптимизация (выигрыш порядка меньше миллисекунды).

Comment: @VladD, а `SemaphoreSlim` тоже использует активное ожидание?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Насколько я понимаю, все `Slim`-версии используют активное ожидание на короткое время, а потом переключаются на стандартный системный механизм. В исходниках: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs,346

Comment: @VladD, получается, то, что я [там](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484669/178988) использую Slim, влияет на результат? Надо было обычный семафор?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм. Ну это да, многопоточное поведение -Slim и не-Slim-версий отличается. Что из них правильнее и больше подходит для твоей задачи — не очевидно.

Comment: @VladD, дедлок при активном ожидании более вероятен - разве нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не, там нет реального активного ожидания. Он просто если не может захватить ресурс сразу, прокручивает 100 или сколько там холостых циклов, и снова пытается, надеясь на то, что ресурс захватили ненадолго (так по идее и должно быть, если программировать по гайдлайнам), и ему повезёт. Если при второй попытке ресурс всё ещё занят, он делает системный вызов и ждёт уже по-настоящему.

Comment: @Qwertiy: То есть семантически это по идее то же самое, что из без активного ожидания. Так что дедлока быть не должно.

Comment: @VladD, думаю, 100 итераций прокручивания вполне хватит, чтобы выполнить пару инкрементов и разблокировок в соседнем потоке?

Comment: @Qwertiy: ну, число 100 взято с потолка, подсмотрю-ка я снова в исходники...

Comment: @VladD, дедлок там by design. И кажется, что активное ожидание делает его более вероятным. Хотя я делаю sleep чтобы его вероятность снизить.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А! Подсмотрел — происходит сначала 4 итерации, потом 8, потом 16, и т. д., до 4096, а затем уходит в `Thread.Sleep(0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С монитором — нет, никак.

Насколько я понимаю, единственный синхронизационный примитив, который позволяет разблокировать себя из другого потока — это `Semaphore` (лучше брать рекомендованный вариант `SemaphoreSlim`).

Пример (на C#)

```
var sema = new SemaphoreSlim(0); // создаём заблокированный семафор
new Thread(() =>
    {
        sema.Release();          // разблокируем его
        // ...
    }).Start();
sema.Wait();                     // ожидаем разблокировки
```

Если вы хотите просто *дождаться* реального старта другого потока, можно использовать `ManualResetEventSlim`.

Код практически такой же:

```
var ev = new ManualResetEventSlim(initialState: false);
new Thread(() =>
    {
        ev.Set();
        // ...
    }).Start();
ev.Wait();
```

---

Поправка: всё-таки исходную проблему *можно* решить с монитором, если заставить его работать как conditional variable. Код получается немного более сложным, и требует вспомогательной булевой переменной:

```
bool started = false;
object mutex = new object();
new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            started = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(mutex);
        }
        // ...
    }).Start();

lock (mutex)
{
    while (!started)
        Monitor.Wait(mutex);    // блокировка будет отпущена на период ожидания
}
```

И наконец, если не только основному потоку нужно дождаться порождённый поток, но и наоборот, порождённый поток должен задержаться до тех пор, пока основной поток не узнает, что он стартовал, у нас возникает так называемая задача *рандеву*: синхронизация одной точки выполнения у нескольких потоков. Это проще всего делать при помощи Barrier:

```
var barrier = new Barrier(participantCount: 2);
new Thread(() =>
{
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // (*)
    // ...
}).Start();

barrier.SignalAndWait();     // (*)
```

Строки, отмеченные звёздочкой, будут ждать друг друга: первый из пришедших в эту строку потоков затормозится до прихода второго.

Comment: Напишу пример кода позже

Comment: Да ладно, и так вроде понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Для будущих поколений :)